# where do i insert values in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

When I insert values in sqlite android, does it happens once or the database is created every time I run my application?

Specifically I have categories that will populate a list (food, drinks ....etc).

Where do I put my insert method?
In my dbHelper class or the class that needs the data?

```
public class ShoppingCategories extends ListActivity{
  private AppSQLite mDbHelper;
  private Cursor mNotesCursor;

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mDbHelper = new AppSQLite(this);
    insertShoppingCategories();
}

public void insertShoppingCategories(){
    mDbHelper.open();
    long id;
    id = mDbHelper.createShoppingCategory("food", 5, "@drawable/ic_launcher");
    id = mDbHelper.createShoppingCategory("drink", 3, "@drawable/ic_launcher");

    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

and the createShoppingCategory from dbHelper class is:

```
   public long createShoppingCategory(String name, int priority, String icon) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PRIORITY, priority);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ICON, icon);

    return mDb.insert(tShopCateg, null, initialValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database is created only if it doesn't exist. If there are values need to be inserted only once you should put them inside `onCreate` inside your `dbHelper` class.

Answer (score 0):

The Database is created once when you create the first instance of the `mDbHelper.open();` (this may change depending on your implementation of the DB Helper class `onCreate()` method). The data you insert in the DB remains in the DB even after the App is closed (this is the reason for having a DB). You use the insert function when you need to save user input in the database persistantly.

Answer (score 0):

put it where you really want to have functionality to insert data at a particular event/instance. You define how you DB would be (table rows and column) in dbHelpr and performs operation like insert delete in the activity.
And yes, DB is created only the first time run of your app when you create the object of dbHelper and db._exec command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Once your database is created it will recreate only if your version of DB is changed or when you clear your data from settings>>Application>>manage Application>>clear data. 
And if you want to insert your data once then you should put that code in onCreat() of dbHelper class.